# Listview items are recreated in wrong order

Tags: android, listview, save

I got a Listview with some String items in it. Im trying to save listview's state in fragment's onStop() method into SharedPreferences:

```
    int    i = 0; 
    HashSet resultsSet = new HashSet(resultAdapter.getCount());

    while (i < resultAdapter.getCount()) {
           resultsSet.add(resultAdapter.getItem(i));  i++;
    }
    editor.putStringSet("RSLTS", resultsSet);
    editor.commit();
```

This is how I recreate Listview's state after relaunching app:

```
     if (resultsSet != null) {
       for (String result : resultsSet) { resultAdapter.insert(result, 0); }
     }
```

As you can see, Im inserting every new line allways at first position (0) of Listview. Problem is that Listview is recreated in some weird order, for example:

> Listview before saving:
> 3... | 2... | 1...
>
> Listview after reloading: 2... | 1... | 3...

Cant figure it out. Why is this happening? Does anybody have some clue whats wrong with it?

Comment: `in wrong order` - Sort the items before putting them into the adapter. If you are extracting the data from a DB, use the `ORDER BY` clause in your query.

Comment: why? i want them in order how are they added when saved. and im extracting data from SharedPreferences:      getActivity().getSharedPreferences("TimerPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: Sets are not ordered collections.

Comment: You can't guess in which order your items will be saved. Nor reloaded

Comment: Does it mean values are inserted at random positions of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HashSet are usually implemented with no defined order, so there is no guarantee the order will remain constant over time or when they are written to strings.

Therefore, your options are:

1) sort your String items if applicable to your case (eg alphabetical)

2) save your data to your shared pref as a concatenated string with a given separator (that you are certain doesn't appear in your data). Then, when you read back it, split the string you get from the shared pref with the given separator, to get the array of original strings.

Comment: omg that's so counter-productive and frustrating. why SharedPreferences.editor doesnt allow to use some normal String[] array?

Comment: Originally, shared prefs was only for primitives + String. They added Set<String> in API 11, which I think confused the issue as developers stopped thinking of it as a store for only primitives + String.

Answer (score 2):

You are using **HashSet** and according to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table (actually a HashMap instance). It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time. This class permits the null element.

So you will need to implement either **TreeSet** or **LinkedHashSet**. An arraylist is also a simple alternative.